# Where can the [%= %] dynamic token syntax be used?

Tags: syntax

I am looking at the old REPORTCENTER onet.xml file in SharePoint 2010's 14 hive (SharePoint Root).  I noticed the following in this file:

```
    <Configuration ID="1" Name="Blank">
        <ExecuteUrl Url="_layouts/[%=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID%]/settings.aspx" />
    </Configuration>
```

The [%=%] syntax jumped out at me.  I assume these are "dynamic" tokens used to access static properties/methods on public classes. The question is, are these run at provisioning time, or at runtime?  Also, is this token syntax only available within the `<ExecuteUrl>` element, or is it available from other elements?  Is there documentation on this syntax?

Comment: This isn't necessarily CAML but rather a call into a .NET class so I removed those references from your question.

Comment: I've only ever seen the square bracket syntax myself in CAML (the angle bracket & percentage symbol being the standard ASP.NET escape sequence).

Answer (score 1):

The [%= is essentially the same thing as using <%= to insert a line of .NET code into an ASP.NET page.  There it is simply grabbing the value of "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID" which I believe it to identify the language code (i.e. 1033 for English).  The only examples where I see that this appears for SharePoint is in the XML template files for site definitions, etc.